# Prepared statement didn't execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have simple web application with back end in PHP. I tried for three hours but couldn't solve the problem.

My code is as follows:

**1. db_connect.php**

```
<?php

define("HOST", '127.0.0.1');
define("USER", 'root');
define("PASSWORD", '');
define("DB", 'tourist guide');


$con = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DB);

if ($con->connect_errno){
    die("Database Connection Failed");
    exit();    
}
```

**2. index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connect.php';

$response = array();       
$result = "";
   

if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['email'])&& isset($_POST['password'])) {
 
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];       
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];     
    $email = $_POST['email'];       
    $password = $_POST['password'];    

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                                      user_accounts
                                      (first_name,last_name,email,password)
                                VALUES
                                      (?,?,?,?)");
                
    echo 'prepared statement executed. ';
                        
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password); 
                
    echo 'values given. ';

    $result = $stmt->execute();
            
    echo 'statement is executed. ';
                              
    $stmt->close();

}
    
if ($result) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "account successfully created.";
    echo json_encode($response);
            
} else {
        
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "An error occurred during registration.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

?>

And the output is as follows:

```
prepared statement executed. values given. statement is executed. {"success":0,"message":"An error occurred during registration."}
```

Only the mistake must be `$result = $stmt->execute();`. Am I wrong here? or the error is something else? plz help.

## UPDATE:

From fred's comment I added:

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
```

Now he real error is showing:

*`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`*

looks like the error is in my database foreign keys...I'll solve it later..If you know about the error right now, then please say me...thanks fred.

Comment: Seems like you're closing your DB connection too soon. Place `$stmt->close();` after `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- so where should I put $stmt->close();?

Comment: Just before your closing `?>` tag. Also make sure your form elements all have a name attribute. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- umm..still showing the same output

Comment: Instead of the whole `if/else` block including `$result = $stmt->execute();` replace with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` to see the real error why it's failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks..that worked..te problem is in my foreign keys in the database...updating question..thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Also `die("Database Connection Failed");` should be `die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');` to get the real error in case your connection should ever fail.

Comment: Try running var_dump($result); directly after the $stmt->execute(); it may well be returning a null set, ie. successfully returning nothing - which you are classifying as a failure.

Test your query seperately alsol.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi..please write answer...so other users can get benefit..I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm writing one up now.

Comment: @xyz Although I am fairly good at SQL, foreign keys are not something that I know very well. However, if you Google the error message "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails mysql" you will get many hits. One of which being https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and others that are listed here on Stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP's wish to close the question, seeing that the error has been found.

It seems like you're closing your DB connection too soon.

Place `$stmt->close();` before your closing `?>` tag.

Also, instead of the whole `if/else` block including `$result = $stmt->execute();` replace it with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("There was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` in order to see the real error why it's failing.

You should also replace `die("Database Connection Failed");` with
`die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');`
to get the real error in case your connection should ever fail.

Seeing that the problem is with your foreign keys.